# What does --allowerasing option in dnf command do?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, perl, kernel-module

I am reading a book which instructs me to install 5.24stream and minimal profile of Perl module by running...

```
dnf module install perl:5.24/minimal --allowerasing
```

Everything was explained in it except the `--allowerasing` option. Can somebody help me what is function of this option?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].

Answer (score 1):

From [DNF Command Reference](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html)

```
--allowerasing
```

Allow erasing of installed packages to resolve dependencies. This option could be used as an alternative to the `yum swap` command where packages to remove are not explicitly defined.